# How to Increase Firefox Sidebar Width

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I coded a sidebar for Firefox like the History and Bookmarks sidebar. In a fresh profile, if I install my add-on and open up the sidebar, the sidebar width gets 216px as default value. But if I grip the right side of the sidebar and drag to right, its width can get to 432px but not more.

How can I set my sidebar's width as 432px as my add-on's default sidebar width?

Comment: Try setting `min-width` maybe `max-width` to. I made a side bar before and controlled the width through style like this: `style: 'min-width: 14em; width: 18em; max-width: 36em;',`

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to add this where? I added it the page element of my sidebar but it did not have any effect?

Comment: Post up your code. Just like you set width set style attribute with this value.

Comment: Did this work out for you man?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really documented, but it can be achieved like this:

```
var sidebar = ui.Sidebar({ ... });
sidebar.show();

var window = require('window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
window.document.getElementById('sidebar').style.width = "400px";
```

Comment: This works OK if the user did not ever modified the width of the sidebar by right side grip. I used sidebar-box instead of sidebar. It would be great if it can modify for the users who already adjusted the width of the sidebar by manual grip. `document.getElementById('sidebar-box').style.width = "400px"`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the sidebar limit by editing your Firefox `userChrome.css`, which can be located by browsing to:
`about:support` --> `Profile Directory` --> `Open Directory`

Add the following to userChrome.css:

```
/* Disable Sidebar width limit */
#sidebar {
  max-width: none !important;
  min-width: 0px !important;
}
```

Restart Firefox for the changes to take effect.

Note 1: If userChrome.css was not found in Firefox profile directory, enable it in `about:config`:

```
toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets = true
```

Note 2: If tag `#sidebar` didn't work, try tag `#sidebar-box`